# calculate expected value of total number of offspring in second generation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose a plant has $X$ offspring per year with $P(X=k) = \frac{1}{4}$ for $k = 1,2,3,4.$

Independently, each offspring has from one to four offspring in the next year with the same discrete uniform distribution. Let $Y$ denote the total number of offspring in the second generation. How to calculate the values of $E(Y|X = k)$ for any outcomes of $X$.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at [this resource](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Generally, if you ask what looks like a homework problem, you'll get downvotes and your question will be closed. Show us that you've tried and are getting stuck somewhere, not that you need to go to office hours.

Comment: I am really confused about it.  kind of stuck how to begin. Any hints

Comment: I guess this is part of a particular type of problems. I can't find any good material on google as of now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start with the definition of expected value:

$$ E[X] = \sum_{i = 1}^n {x*P[X = x]} .$$

If we add in the condition, this becomes:

$$ E[Y | X = x] = \sum_{i = 1}^n {y*P[Y = y | X = x]} .$$

Now, start by asking what happens if the plant has $X = 1$ offspring? There are four possibilities: $Y = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Each has probability $\frac{1}{4}$. So, that gives you the first part of your answer:

$$ E[Y | X = 1] = 1*\frac{1}{4} + 2*\frac{1}{4} + 3*\frac{1}{4} + 4*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{2} .$$

Next, consider what happens when $X = 2$. Now, $Y = 1$ is not possible - each of the two plants in the first generation must have a minimum of $1$ offspring. So, okay, what about $Y = 2$? Well, that is possible. It happens if each of the first two has $1$ offspring, which has probability $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{16}$. Now, what about the probability that $Y = 3$? Well, that can happen two ways - the first offspring has $1$ and the second $2$, or vice versa. So, that probability is $2*\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{8}$. The probability that $Y = 4$ is $3*\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{3}{16}$ - that's from offspring possibilities of $1$ and $3$, $2$ and $2$, or $3$ and $1$. Keep going through all possible values of $Y | X = 2$. Then, you'll be able to calculate

$$ E[Y | X = 2] = 2*\frac{1}{16} + 3*\frac{1}{8} + 4*\frac{3}{16} + ... $$

You can keep going this route and brute force your way through the problem, or look for a pattern, but that's how to start thinking about this problem.